# Struggle clicking a a window closing button with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm struggling to click on a specific object with selenium. [HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMgTL.png)

What I've tried so far, unsuccessfully:

`webD.find_element_by_link_text('Apply').click()`

`WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/button'))).click()`

`webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/button').click()`

`WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Apply'))).click()`

And myriads in between. The final code is the one I was most optimistic about.... Turns out the button changes from "close" to "apply" once a selection is done, so I figured by waiting for the element to appear and then click it could work. I think I'm missing something here. Maybe I don't require a wait at all..
Clicking the apply button closes the selection window (which is what I'm trying to do).

Any insight on why these are wrong? Any idea how to correct this issue? Thank you so much in advance! Looking forward to reading your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following `xpath` to click on the button.

```
WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Apply')]"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked instantly. Could you enlighten me why my intuition wasn't sufficient/wrong? 

Thanks so much

Comment: @RyeRye : If you see your xpath its asking for a button to click however not mentioned which button it should click. As you said it is changing text from close to Apply you need to look for valid xpath to identify the correct element.